# For some reason im getting wrong result using fork

Tags: c, fork

The program creates a child proccess and the child does the proper work in order to see if its pid is even or odd

And for some reason even if the pid is even i get that it is odd , also the parent waits for child

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <unistd.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <sys/wait.h>


int main() {
    pid_t pid, mypid, cpid;
    int flag;
    pid = getpid();
    printf("Process %d creates new process\n\n", pid);
    cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == 0) {
        cpid=getpid();
        printf("\n----[%d] child\n", cpid);
        if (cpid % 2 == 0) {
            flag = 1;
        } else {
            flag = 0;
        }
        exit(0);
    } else if (cpid != 0) {    
        wait(NULL);
        mypid = getpid();
        printf("\n[%d] parent of [%d]\n", mypid, cpid);
        if (flag == 1) {
            printf("\nThe child pid is even");
        } else if(flag ==0) {
            printf("\nThe child pid is odd");
        } else {
            printf("\nSomething went wrong");
        }
    } else {
        perror("Fork failed");
}

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect will ever set `flag` in the parent process?

Comment: The variables in the program are not shared between the child *process* and the parent *process* because processes do not shared address space. If you want independent execution of code that shares address space then you need to implement a threaded application not a multi-process application.

Comment: Or alternatively establish some sort of inter process communication